# jQuery Cycle2 sideshow caption text fade?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-cycle2

I am looking for help to get the caption text to fade in Cycle 2.  My text is outside of the slides, which do fade. The answers offered up here in similar are not working for me. Here is my slideshow:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" 

data-cycle-fx="fade"

data-cycle-speed="slow" 

data-cycle-timeout="0" 

data-cycle-pager="#no-template-pager" 

data-cycle-pager-template=""

data-cycle-caption="#alt-caption" 

data-cycle-caption-template="{{alt}}"
>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-before', function (opts) {
    var slideshow = $(this);
    var img = slideshow.find('.banner-background').css('background-image');
    slideshow.css('background-image', img);
});
```

I have answered similar questions like this before: here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/defonic/npqB5/